When to flag "not an answer"?
I have been flagging a lot of answers lately that were actually no answers, but comments or new questions - today one of those flags was declined, because "it shouldn't be used to flag wrong answers", in a case where I had clearly flagged a follow-up question. The flag description of "not an answer" seems to be indicating that this is the proper use of that flag.
Apparently, I am confused about how to use the "not an answer" flag. How is it supposed to be used?
Edit: The flagged answer can be found here: How to import my wallet?
The decline was explained with "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

If sounds like you've been using this feature successfully up until this one case. So can you add a link to the post in question so we can discuss the specifics of whether it should have been declined (and why), rather than guessing about generalizations?

"Not an answer" was created to address the issue of folks leaving commentary, or even additional questions as answers. It also applies when someone just typed an answer to another question in the wrong box in the wrong tab (that happens more than you'd think). You can also use it when something is completely out of left field and just bizarre in the context of the question, e.g:

Q: How do I calculate how many [something] my [something] did?

And then you see this ...

A: I like turtles. 

You should not use the flag to indicate that an answer is inaccurate or just plain wrong, that's what votes and comments are for. If it attempts to answer the question, even if it's obvious that the question was misunderstood, it's still an answer.
If you think that it wouldn't be immediately obvious to the moderators that the answer you're flagging should probably be removed (generally, the usual course for valid flags of this type), use 'other' and elaborate a bit - make sure the moderators notice what you did.
